# Share the dist folder of loopback4

Tags: node.js, build, loopbackjs, production, loopback4

I just build the dist folder of my Loopback 4 API and wish to deploy it on one of my machines.

1. `npm run build && tar -zxvf dist.tar.gz ./dist` (Move the dist.tar.gz file on another machine + untar it)
2. Try to run it: `node ./dist/index.js`
3. Get this error: `tslib package not found`.

Is there something I'm missing?
There is no packages.json in the dist folder then no way to install the dependencies... Should I add a flag or something? (I didn't find any explanation in the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with other TypeScript projects, LoopBack 4 projects requires `dist`, `package.json`, `package-lock.json` to be published.

In production, you can run this command to skip the build process and instead execute the pre-built artifacts:

```
node .
```

Comment: Yes in the end i add a 'build:prod' script in the package.json that is making a copy of the package.json and lock for the production version (I removed the 'developpement' dependencies)

Then the build:prop basically run the build + a node script that is making the copy of the files in the dist directory

Comment: I expect to deploy `dist` folder for the production server because it's not reasonable to deploy the entire directory with all used development dependencies. Furthermore, I think `build:prod` should be existed in LoopBack (I'll open a feature request for it)

Comment: I opened a feature request [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/6895)

Comment: @mbnoimi I think there was some confusion on the initial answer. To relay what I've said in the GitHub issue: It's not mandatory to publish everything, it's just a catch-all statement for unknown edge-cases where a novice user may have inexplicably required something outside of `dist`. I've updated the answer to remove this remark as it seems to cause confusion on what's actually required.

Comment: @rifa-achrinza Thanks for the clarification.
I did as you suggested by running `npm start --ignore-scripts` but it didn't start and I'm unable to see anything in the terminal. I successfully run `node ./dist/index.js` after running `npm install`

Comment: Sorry about that - mistook NPM's `--ignore-scripts` behaviour. I've updated the answer with your suggestion.